# How to create a new object in Saleor Commerce?

Tags: python, django, saleor

Could somebody guide me how to add a new object to the projects? For example, **Banner**. Dashboard should be able to create, edit, delete banners. The banners will then be display on the storefront.

I'm new to Python/Django. I watch a tutorial and find out that I may need to create an app so I do:
`python manage.py startapp banner`
but it always show the error: `No module named 'module names'` . After I install one it shows another.
I've already run `docker-compose build` before, and I think it should already install everything.

Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the Storefront

**Important Files**

```
saleor-storefront/config/webpack/config.base.js - Base webpack config file.
    Can change name of the app (displayed when installed on mobile)
saleor-storefront/src/index.html - Main template file that contains the <div id="root"></div>
    Can change title of storefront here
saleor-storefront/src/index.tsx - Main entry point file. Render's the <App /> component, apollo-client, and others to the root div in index.html file above.
saleor-storefront/src/core/config.ts - Controls number of products shown per page, support email, gateway providers, social media, and some meta.
    Can change support email
    Can change products shown per page
    Can change gateway providers
    Can change social media links that are displayed in the footer
    Can change some meta options
saleor-storefront/src/images/ - Holds all the images for logo, cart, favicon, etc.
    Can change storefront logo, favicon, or add new images here. Easiest way I've found is to save saleor's logos as backups (logo-backup.svg) and insert your own and mess around till you get it looking the way you want and get rid of backups. I'm not a graphic person so not sure the best way.
saleor-storefront/src/globalStyles/scss/variables.scss - Contains base styles like colors, font size, container width, media breakpoints and more.
saleor-storefront/src/@next/globalStyles/ - Contains more base styles, themes, media, and constants.
saleor-storefront/src/views/ - This folder controls the views, or what is displayed for each page. The way Saleor has it setup, most views have a file named "Page.tsx" that controls the layout of the page and a file named "View.tsx" that calls the query and renders the <Page /> component with the data.
    Can add another view to storefront here. Requires adding a route (see routes below).
saleor-storefront/src/@next/pages/ - Second spot for modifying/adding different pages. This is the recommended directory to add new pages.
saleor-storefront/src/app/routes/ - This folder contains the paths as well as holds the <Routes /> component. Here is where you add a new path and route.
    Export a new path in paths.ts
    Inside AppRoutes.tsx import your new view (see views above) and create a new route with path={paths.newPath} and component={newViewPage}
    To link to your new view import { Link } from "react-router-dom" and use new path you created in paths.ts (make sure to import it)
saleor-storefront/src/app/App.tsx - This is main <App /> component that renders the <MainMenu />, <Routes /> (explained below), <Footer /> and a couple other components.
```

**Adding a Payment Gateway**

```
saleor-storefront/src/core/config.ts - Add new gateway provider name here.
saleor-storefront/src/@next/components/organisms/ - Create a new folder for new payment gateway component here.
saleor-storefront/src/@next/components/organisms/PaymentGatewaysList/PaymentGatewaysList.tsx - Import new gateway component, create a new switch case to handle your gateway component.
```

**Receiving confirmation emails**

```
Set EMAIL_URL environment variable for Saleor core.
    Using Docker - Add EMAIL_URL as new enviornment variable to both the api and worker service following the format here.
Issues getting emails working?
    Gmail
        Check to see that "Less secure app access" is turned ON. Under "Manage your Google Account" > Go to the security tab. By default, the setting is off for security reasons.
        If using 2FA make sure to set an app password and use that in place of your normal login password.
```

SOURCE: [https://spectrum.chat/saleor/saleor-storefront/modifying-the-storefront~c1955dbf-a421-4fb6-b99e-937dd2642b23](https://spectrum.chat/saleor/saleor-storefront/modifying-the-storefront%7Ec1955dbf-a421-4fb6-b99e-937dd2642b23)